# CSS first-child selector doesn't select first element

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why if I put an element before the "p" lines, I don't see the first line yellow? Should `p:first-child` select the very first `p` and not just a very first tag?

```html
<style type="text/css">
    p:first-child 
    {
        background:yellow;
    }
</style>


<i></i>
<p>I am a strong man. I am a strong man.</p>
<p>I am a strong man. I am a strong man.</p>
<p>I am a strong man. I am a strong man.</p>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`:first-child` does not care about the type. By adding `<i></i>` to your code, `i` becomes the first child (assuming `<style>` is within `<head>` and the rest is in `<body>`, of course). Your selector wants to match `p`, but since `p` is not the first child anymore, your style can't be applied.

If you want to filter by type, use the CSS3 `:first-of-type` pseudo-class:

```
p:first-of-type
{
    background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: i actually found myslf it might be easier to wrap the elements in a parent wrapper div and than specify that in css...it works..

Comment: @camelCase: Not really. And yes, you're way better off wrapping your `p` elements in a `div`. It doesn't make much sense to have an `i` before a series of `p`s anyway.